# Как мне обработать определенную фразу из предложения в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Мне нужно обрабатывать фразу, которую отправляют моему боту в Telegram. Проблема в том, что фразу могут использовать в предложение. Что мне делать?

Comment: `if "фраза" in message`?

Comment: `if message.text == "фраза"` - но так он обрабатывает фразу в сообщение.

Answer (score 1):

Есть два пути.

- Первый путь это модуль [fuzzy buzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/).
- А второй путь используя `find()` .

  Например:

  ```
     if( command.find(“hello”)> -1):

     # do some actions
  ```